# How can I provide my custom OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider in spring boot

Tags: apache, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to setup OAuth2 login in spring boot, every thing is working good in my dev environment, however when I deploy it on production behind the Apache Http server using proxy configuration, authentication fails on Invalid Redirect URI check.

As suggested in some other post I already tried 
1. use-forward-headers: true
2. Rewriting the request redirect URI
with no luck.
So I decided to hook my own custom OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider so that I can override this check.

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Value("${baseUrl}")
    private String domainPath;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .addFilterBefore(new MyCustomFilter(domainPath), OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .and()
            .oauth2Login().userInfoEndpoint().customUserType(CmmOAuth2User.class, "custom");

    }

    @Bean
    public MyOAuth2AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        MyOAuth2AuthenticationProvider authProvider
          = new MyOAuth2AuthenticationProvider();

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureProviderManager(ProviderManager providerManager) {
        providerManager.getProviders().add(0,authenticationProvider());
    }
    @Bean
    public ProviderManager authenticationManager() {
        List<AuthenticationProvider> authProviderList = new ArrayList<AuthenticationProvider>();
        authProviderList.add(0,authenticationProvider());
        ProviderManager providerManager = new ProviderManager(authProviderList);
        return providerManager;
    }


}
```

My custom MyOAuth2AuthenticationProvider is not being called.

Comment: Please provide full code for MyOAuth2AuthenticationProvider